# Change languages URL route from 'en_US' to 'en'

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-router

Zend languages is by default routing urls that way:

```
/en_US/mypage
/fr_FR/mypage
```

How can I change the route from 'en_US' to 'en' and 'fr_FR' to 'fr', example:

```
/en/mypage
/fr/mypage
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply process the url by cutting it up as a string.  If its . Here is simplistic suedocode:

```
my_url = "http://whatever/en_US/mypage";
first_half = "http://whatever/en";
second_half = "/mypage";

my_url = first_half + second_half;
```